# Portainer docker container reverse proxy issue

Tags: docker, nginx, proxy, portainer

I have a CentOC virtual machine running inside Freenas. I have docker installed on the virtual machine with a number of containers. I have nginx container receiving local (port 80 and 443) and external traffic (port 443). I am trying to set up a virtual host for portainer but I am only getting partial success. Here is my configurations:

nginx.conf

```
user  www-data;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/debug.log debug;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {worker_connections  1024;}

http {

upstream backend {server app-server:9000;}
upstream onlyoffice {server onlyoffice-document-server:443;}

## allow cloudflare only ips
include /etc/nginx/myconfig/cloudflare.conf;

include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

keepalive_timeout  65;


##  proxy mappings
include /etc/nginx/myconfig/proxy.conf;

##
# HTTP host for internal services only
##
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name localhost;
    server_tokens off;
    ## Redirects all traffic to the HTTPS host
    root /nowhere; ## root doesn't have to be a valid path since we are redirecting
    rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
}

##
## HTTPS host
##
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name cloud.mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
    server_tokens off;
    root /var/www/html;

    ## block non-cloudflare ips
    if ($cloudflare_ip != 1) {return 444;}

    ## SSL settings
    include /etc/nginx/myconfig/ssl.conf;


    client_max_body_size 1G; # 0=unlimited - set max upload size
    fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

    # Enable gzip but do not remove ETag headers
    include /etc/nginx/myconfig/gzip.conf;

    index index.php;
    error_page 403 /core/templates/403.php;
    error_page 404 /core/templates/404.php;

    rewrite ^/.well-known/carddav /remote.php/dav/ permanent;
    rewrite ^/.well-known/caldav /remote.php/dav/ permanent;



    ## Locations
    ###

    # For Letsencrypt certificate verification
    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        root /var/www/html/;
        allow all;
    }

    # Locations (nextcloud, calibre, onlyoffice, portainer, etc) on www. and cloud.
    include /etc/nginx/myconfig/locations/*.conf;

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
}
    # virtual hosts
    include  /etc/nginx/myconfig/vhosts/*.conf;
}
```

portainer.conf

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name portainer.mydomain.com;
    location / {
      return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name portainer.mydomain.com;
    resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s ipv6=off;
    set $upstream http://portainer:9000;

    ssl_certificate /keys/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /keys/server.key;

    proxy_redirect          off;
    proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    client_max_body_size    10m;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_connect_timeout   90;
    proxy_send_timeout      90;
    proxy_read_timeout      90;
    proxy_buffers           32 4k;


    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_pass $upstream;  #tried this with and without trailing slash
    }

    location /api/websocket/ {
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass $upstream/api/websocket;  #tried this with and without trailing slash
    }

}
```

When I navigate to portainer.mydomain.com, the main auth page opens up but this error message at the top right corner.

```
    Failure
    [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration for action `query`. Expected response to contain an array but got an object (Request: GET api/endpoints) http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.11/$resource/badcfg?p0=query&p1=array&p2=object&p3=GET&p4=api%2Fendpoints
```

Nothing happens when I enter user/pass and press login.

Screenshot:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8zneoz21d8zq0au/portainer_image.jpg?dl=0

Note that connecting directly to portainer via the exposed port 9000 on my dockerhost is working just fine.

Please help me fix this.

UPDATE 5/12/2018: problem solved. Turns out it was a problem with Firefox caching content as I was testing different configurations. I cleared the cache and now everything is working fine :)

Comment: Hi @Saeed. Your question really helped me out. Would love to see the whole config, especially the mappings and whitelist ips, but generally just the setup of the different files/directories if you have an example you can point me to :)